# Discretization of generalized kinetic term in 2D Poisson partial differential equation

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, poisson-equation

A typical 2D Poisson PDE is given as
$$\nabla^2\varphi(x, y)=f(x, y)$$
where the Laplacian term, $\nabla^2\varphi$, can to some degree be interpreted as the kinetic energy (given proper scaling) (Laplacian term in the Schroedinger-like equations, such as Ginzburg-Landau or Gross-Pitaevskii). However, in the mentioned equations, particularly in the Ginzburg-Landau equation accounting for the presence of magnetic field, one deals with slightly different kinetic term: $(\nabla-iA)^2\varphi$, where **A** is a dimensionless vector potential.

When dealing with $\nabla^2\varphi$, one can, within finite difference terminology, discretize the kinetic term as:
$$\nabla^2\varphi\propto\frac{\varphi_{i+1,j}-2\varphi_{i,j}+\varphi_{i-1,j}}{\Delta x^2}+\frac{\varphi_{i,j+1}-2\varphi_{i,j}+\varphi_{i,j-1}}{\Delta y^2}$$
in case when rectangular grid is consider with unit cell of size $\Delta x\times\Delta y$.

What I would like to know is how do we generally handle the modified kinetic term with the vector potential under discretization?

Based on some literature I've found up to now, a concept of *link variables* is introduced, but this coming from the superconductivity literature (Ginzburg-Landau formalism) is typically given ad-hoc without any motivation or background described. An example can be seen in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0106466.pdf). There, since the vector potential is also an unknown function described with an additional differential equation, an explanation is provided in the form that points where **A** is calculated at come with offset with respect to the points where $\varphi$ is calculated at, so the link variable transformations compensate for that. I wonder if this is the only way to tackle this problem or there exists a more optimal discretization methodology?

**Edit**

After a bit of researching, I've encountered [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9803218.pdf). Apparently, the link-variable approach arises from the gauge-invariant grid discretization, and it was first introduced [here](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.10.2445). That is why it is sometimes called *Wilson's formulation of lattice gauge theories*. However, what I still fail to understand is under what conditions should one use the link variables when dealing with Laplacian of the form $(\nabla-iA)^2\varphi$ and when a straightforward approach ($\nabla^2\varphi-i2A\cdot\nabla\varphi-\varphi\nabla A-|A|^2\varphi$) can be used.

Any inputs on this would be welcome.

Comment: From looking at the paper, they're not using $\nabla - A$ but rather $\nabla - iA$. The factor of the imaginary unit is very important because it means that this operator is skew-adjoint. If you were to discretize it, you'd want to make sure that the discretized operator has the same property. Likewise, $(\nabla - iA)^2$ is self-adjoint, and you'd want the same feature in a discretization.

Comment: @DanielShapero, thanks for the comment. I will update the main post so it's corrected there.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not 100% sure, but this is what I would do.

If you are using a central differencing scheme for the gradient, then

$\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - A_x \right) \phi \approx \frac{\phi_{i+1, j} - \phi_{i-1, j}}{2 \Delta x} - A_{x, ij} \phi_{ij}
$

$\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - A_y \right) \phi \approx \frac{\phi_{i, j+1} - \phi_{i, j-1}}{2 \Delta y} - A_{y, ij} \phi_{ij}.
$

Substituting these in the kinetic term gives

$\left( \nabla - \mathbf{A} \right)^2 \phi \approx \left[ \left( \frac{\phi_{i+1, j} - \phi_{i-1, j}}{2 \Delta x} - A_{x, ij} \phi_{ij} \right) \right]^2 + \left[ \left( \frac{\phi_{i, j+1} - \phi_{i, j-1}}{2 \Delta y} - A_{y, ij} \phi_{ij} \right) \right]^2
$

However, this discretized equation does not simplify down to

$\nabla^2 \phi \approx \frac{\phi_{i+1, j} - 2\phi_{i, j} + \phi_{i-1, j}}{\left(\Delta x \right)^2} + \frac{\phi_{i, j+1} - 2\phi_{i, j} + \phi_{i, j-1}}{\left(\Delta y \right)^2}
$

when $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0}$.

Comment: I don't think that anything resembling $\phi^2$ should appear in these equations. The operator is being applied twice.

Comment: @whpowell96, indeed, this approach is wrong, as operator should be squared, and not the entire expression. The proper expanded term is, assuming that we do not need any special transformation (e.g., link variables): $\nabla^2\varphi-A\cdot\nabla\varphi-\nabla(A\varphi)+|A|^2\varphi$.